# Add third level to php menu in WP?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dynamic, menu

I'm attempting to add a for loop to a php menu that will add a tertiary level to a currently existing WP menu.  Unfortunately, the only editable amount of content is that posted below, so please bear with me on this one.
I'm just wondering, before I attempt to implement this code, if anyone can tell me if it will actually work, of if you assume it'll break everything.

What I've done is to take the same semantic forloop that was written for the secondary (or 'sub_nav') menu items, and repeat it in attempts to dynamically generate third level (or 'tert_nav') menu items.

```
<div class="main-menu-sub-navigation">
<?php
    $main_nav_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items(2);
    $sub_nav = array();
    foreach ($main_nav_items as $item) {
        if($item->menu_item_parent !== '0'){
            $parent_id = $item->menu_item_parent;
            $sub_nav[$parent_id][] = array('item' => $item);
        }
    }
    $tert_nav = array();
    foreach ($sub_nav_items as $item) {
        if($item->menu_item_parent !== '0'){
            $parent_id = $item->menu_item_parent;
            $tert_nav[$parent_id][] = array('item' => $item);
        }
    }
?>
<div class="sub-nav-inner">
    <?php foreach ($sub_nav as $key => $value) { ?>
        <ul class="nav sub-nav" data-parent="<?php print $key; ?>">
            <?php foreach ($value as $item) { ?>
                <?php if(isset($_GET['archive'])): ?>
                    <li class="menu-item-<?php print $item['item']->object_id; ?> <?php print ($item['item']->title == 'Archives') ? 'current-menu-item' : 'menu-item'; ?>"><a href="<?php print $item['item']->url; ?>"><?php print $item['item']->title; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($tert_nav as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <ul class="nav tert-nav" data-parent="<?php print $key; ?>">
                                <?php foreach ($value as $item) { ?>
                                    <?php if(isset($_GET['archive'])): ?>
                                        <li class="menu-item-<?php print $item['item']->object_id; ?> <?php print ($item['item']->title == 'Archives') ? 'current-menu-item' : 'menu-item'; ?>"><a href="<?php print $item['item']->url; ?>"><?php print $item['item']->title; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <li class="menu-item-<?php print $item['item']->object_id; ?> <?php print ($item['item']->object_id == get_the_ID()) ? 'current-menu-item' : 'menu-item'; ?>"><a href="<?php print $item['item']->url; ?>"><?php print $item['item']->title; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li class="menu-item-<?php print $item['item']->object_id; ?> <?php print ($item['item']->object_id == get_the_ID()) ? 'current-menu-item' : 'menu-item'; ?>"><a href="<?php print $item['item']->url; ?>"><?php print $item['item']->title; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($sub_nav as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <ul class="nav tert-nav" data-parent="<?php print $key; ?>">
                                <?php foreach ($value as $item) { ?>
                                    <?php if(isset($_GET['archive'])): ?>
                                        <li class="menu-item-<?php print $item['item']->object_id; ?> <?php print ($item['item']->title == 'Archives') ? 'current-menu-item' : 'menu-item'; ?>"><a href="<?php print $item['item']->url; ?>"><?php print $item['item']->title; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <li class="menu-item-<?php print $item['item']->object_id; ?> <?php print ($item['item']->object_id == get_the_ID()) ? 'current-menu-item' : 'menu-item'; ?>"><a href="<?php print $item['item']->url; ?>"><?php print $item['item']->title; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be so very greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: Edited code snippet:

Comment: I changed the semantics of each forloop to target the $tert_menu in the right places.  Still need an opinion, though.

Comment: Can you help understand why you aren't using the WP native function [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)? It seems as though you're doing this the hard way....

Comment: I understand, but I'm only tasked with editing what is currently there, not to rewrite, or use any different route.  Unfortunately, my hands are tied.